# Drawables not loading with coil in release build after applying dexguard

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, dexguard, coil

I am using coil(Kotlin) library to load drawables. Working fine in debug build but after generating release build with dexguard no drawable loads.

Library I am using

```
 implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.1.0")

  ivGlowingCircles.load(R.drawable.glowing_circles)
```